# How to resolve the accuracy error with floating point arithmetic

Tags: java, math, currency, floating-accuracy

I am trying to make a program that calculates the equivalent amount of change for a given amount of money. Everything in the program works well until I get to pennies. When I get to pennies, I've done so much floating point arithmetic that the value becomes inaccurate. Here is the output:

[image]

As we can see, rather than have 0.2 (which I would divide by 0.1 to get 2, the correct answer), we have 019999999999959064 (which when divided by 0.01 to get the amount of pennies, we get 1 not 2). How can I resolve this issue so that I can get the correct amount of pennies?

Comment: Change to `BigDecimal` / store pennies separately / multiply everything by 100 and do your operations after then

Comment: You should use `BigDecimal` if you need super precision.

Comment: Currency is not a floating point value.  Currency is a fixed point value.  Stop being a goofball and using floating point for currency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Floating point is not a good choice for modelling exact monetary values.

Either (i), use a `long` type and work in pence, or (ii) use a class designed to model money.

Answer (score 2):

### Diatribe

Stop using floating point to represent currency.
BigDecimal is just as bad, but will have fewer precision (perhaps none) issues.

If you use BigDecimal,
I suggest that you include the following comment in your code:

```
// Danger, this code written by a goofball (insert your name here).
```

### The Real Solution

Use longs and represent values starting at a meaningful (to your situation) fraction of a penny; perhaps 1000th of a penny.
Even if you represent 1,000,000th of a penny,
a long still provides plenty of room to significantly more than 
$9,223,372,036.99
which is likely to be larger than any transaction you need to process.

Comment: I feel your pain. Now, breathe with me. In ... and Out ... Again. In ... and Out ... Feel better? Now could you dial back the diatribe just a bit? Like, the comment part? Thanks

Comment: So why is using BigDecimal just as bad? The only reason I can think of is speed. The advantage is that it does not require any extra processing, like dividing by the fixed scale each time. And for small values, BigDecimal uses a long to represent the unscaled value too, so ISTM that using a long for currency is re-inventing the wheel. Is there no (fixed point) Currency type, like in some other languages?

Comment: The problem with using fixed precision long is there is a risk you will get the order of magnitude wrong. e.g. you have trade where price * quantity is out by a factor of ten or more.  I would rather be out by 0.000000000001 cents.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use appropriate rounding. Even if you use `long` or `BigDecimal` rounding issues don't go away, though in this case it would be much simpler.

A good place to start is rounding to a `long` number of cents.

```
double value = 586.67;
long v = Math.round(value * 100.0); // the fact you used a double is fine.
long hundreds = v / 100;
v -= hundreds * 100;
long fifties = v / 50;
v -= fifties * 50;
long twenties = v / 20;
v -= twenties * 20;
long tens = v / 10;
v -= tens * 10;
```

You could do this with double, however you would need to round each step of the way, which is more complicated in this example.

Comment: Unlike the one with the diatribe, this is the only useful solution. Since we are talking about an amount of change, it makes no sense to use anything else but a long (or int) to represent cents (or whatever 1/100 of the main currency is called). Also, your sequence of division and subtraction is far more elegant than the extreme cascade of `) % 20) % 10) etc...`.

Answer (score 0):

Math.round is one way to solve this but I would not recommend it.

another way is to use BigDeciaml which is a lot a more accurate especially when dealing with currency

Another way in which I read about recently is to work in whole numbers until the end eg work in cents instead of dollars so $1  would be 100 instead and work from there instead.

I hope these ideas help

[very intereesting video on floating points in general](https://youtu.be/PZRI1IfStY0?t=455)

[math api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float))